If the taylor expansion at a point converges in an interval, so does the taylor expansion at every other point in that interval?
Apostol's Calculus defined analyticity on an inteval as follows:

A function $f$ is said to be analytic on an interval $(x_0-r,x_0+r) $ if $$f(x)=\sum_0^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(x_0)}{n!}(x-x_0)^n$$ for $|x-x_0|<r$

On the other hand, most defintions I've encountered on the internet are

A function $f$ is said to be analytic on an interval $I$ if $$f(x)=\sum_0^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(x_0)}{n!}(x-x_0)^n$$ in some neighbourhood of $x_0$ for each $x_0 \in I$ .

Are these two defintions equivalent? Does the convergence of a taylor series in an interval centered at a point imply the convergence of the taylor series centered at every point in that interval?

Yes, the definitions are equivalent.

@EthanBolker Could you elaborate a bit more, with some justification

No time to prove the theorem now. This might help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_continuation

Any power series on the real numbers extends naturally to a power series on the complex numbers: just replace the real variable with a complex one. The radius of convergence does not change. The function is complex differentiable. But by the Cauchy-Goursat theorem and Cauchy's integral formula, any complex function which is differentiable on a neighborhood of a point $a$ is infinitely differentiable and equal to its power series about $a$. I.e. Thus if a function equals its taylor series at $x_0$ it also equals its power series at $a$ for all $a$ in the radius of convergence
